# Different Messages Based on WooCommerce Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, notice

I am trying to alter messages displayed when adding an a product to cart and/ or updating the cart by hooking in to the `woocommerce_add_message`. It's not showing anything at all and I'm wondering why.

I've tried `echo` and I've tried `return__(`
Here's the code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', 'change_cart_message', 10);
function change_cart_message() {

    $ncst = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        echo 'Your new order subtotal is: '.$ncst.'. <a style="color: green;" href="#customer_details">Ready to checkout?</a>';
    }
    elseif ( is_product() ) {
        echo 'Your new order subtotal is: '.$ncst.'. <a style="color: green;" href="'.wc_get_checkout_url().'">Ready to checkout?</a>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Your new order subtotal is: '.$ncst.'. <a style="color: green;" href="'.wc_get_checkout_url().'">Ready to checkout?</a>';
    } 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Important note: A filter hook has always a variable argument to be returned.**

When using a filter hook, you need always **to return** the filtered value argument (but not to echo it)…

Also your code can be simplified and compacted:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', 'change_cart_message', 10, 1 );
function change_cart_message( $message ) {

    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    $href = is_checkout() ? '#customer_details' : wc_get_checkout_url();

    return sprintf(  __("Your new order subtotal is: %s. %s"), wc_price($subtotal),
        '<a class="button alt" href="'.$href.'">' . __("Ready to checkout?") . '</a>' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works but it does not scroll down to the checkout details.

Comment: okay, I'll ask a new question. I was more thinking since you are (I think?) linking to the section in your answer ('#customer_details'), but it's not working. I apoligize if I'm mistaken.

Comment: this seems such a weird hard wired filter. is it only called when the cart is updated on the cart page?

Comment: @dewd it's triggered by `wc_add_notice()` function on "succes" notice type only.