# Message with Link and Scroll to Woocommerce Checkout Details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, notice

I got this answer from LoicTheAztec which solves the problem with the message. But, when clicking the button, it does not scroll down to the customer details on the Checkout page, which is the idea.

Hers's the code from LoicTheAztec:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', 'change_cart_message', 10, 1 );
function change_cart_message( $message ) {

    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    $href = is_checkout() ? '#customer_details' : wc_get_checkout_url();

    return sprintf(  __("Your new order subtotal is: %s. %s"), wc_price($subtotal),
        '<a class="button alt" href="'.$href.'">' . __("Ready to checkout?") . '</a>' );
}
```

Can I please get help with that?
[Here's the link that question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366556/different-messages-based-on-woocommerce-page)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, can you please answer here with the scroll to #customer_details? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the scroll to checkout "Customer details" section, you will need to replace the following line:

```
$href = is_checkout() ? '#customer_details' : wc_get_checkout_url();
```

by:

```
$href = is_checkout() ? '#customer_details' : wc_get_checkout_url() . '#customer_details';
```

Comment: I apologize. To fast copy/ paste (spelling error). It works fine. Thank you very very much for your kind help.

Comment: may I kindly ask for an explanation so that I understand what you have done? this line: `$href = is_checkout() ? '#customer_details' : wc_get_checkout_url() . '#customer_details';`

why format it that way?

Comment: @JessicaMcKay  It is just a way to compact the code as it will be the same thing than: `if( is_checkout() ) { $href = '#customer_details'; } else { $href = wc_get_checkout_url() . '#customer_details'; }` …